# Is there any general rule on SQL query complexity Vs performance?

Tags: sql, performance, big-o

1)Are SQL query execution times O(n) compared to the number of joins, if indexes are not used? If not, what kind of relationship are we likely to expect? And can indexing improve the actual big-O time-complexity, or does it only reduce the entire query time by some constant factor?

Slightly vague question, I'm sure it varies a lot but I'm talking in a general sense here.

2) If you have a query like:

```
SELECT  T1.name, T2.date
FROM    T1, T2
WHERE   T1.id=T2.id
        AND T1.color='red'
        AND T2.type='CAR'
```

Am I right assuming the DB will do single table filtering first on T1.color and T2.type, before evaluating multi-table conditions? In such a case, making the query more complex could make it faster because less rows are subjected to the join-level tests?

Comment: I'd think there is a huge dependency on how your database is designed (e.g., indexes) and what's in the query, so its not just a situation where you can look at the query and give a definite answer.  Query Analyzer is going to be your best bet in figuring out what to change in your query and your database to get the fastest results.

Comment: So you're telling me DB design has no underlying scientific principles? I don't buy it, there's loads of CS theory on databases.

Comment: @John, there are lots of sound principles for database design, and even more people who don't know those principles. Nothing guarantees that good design principles have been applied to any specific database. As Will said, Query Analyzer is indeed the best way to go. Look at the execution plan. Look at the indexes selected, and note where indexes might be needed, or might exist but are not being used. Run SQL Profiler and collect performance logs, then analyze those logs.

Comment: Cylon, yes that's why I'm asking the question, to learn more about the theory. Profilers should be used to optimise a database,not design it!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This depends on the query plan used.

Even without indexes, modern servers can use `HASH JOIN` and `MERGE JOIN` which are faster than `O(N * M)`

More specifically, complexity of a `HASH JOIN` is `O(N + M)`, where `N` is the hashed table and `M` the is lookup table. Hashing and hash lookups have constant complexity.

Complexity of a `MERGE JOIN` is `O(N*Log(N) + M*Log(M))`: it's the sum of times to sort both tables plus time to scan them.

```
SELECT  T1.name, T2.date
FROM    T1, T2
WHERE   T1.id=T2.id
        AND T1.color='red'
        AND T2.type='CAR'
```

If there are no indexes defined, the engine will select either a `HASH JOIN` or a `MERGE JOIN`.

The `HASH JOIN` works as follows:

1. The hashed table is chosen (usually it's the table with fewer records). Say it's `t1`
2. All records from `t1` are scanned. If the records holds `color='red'`, this record goes into the hash table with `id` as a key and `name` as a value.
3. All records from `t2` are scanned. If the record holds `type='CAR'`, its `id` is searched in the hash table and the values of `name` from all hash hits are returned along with the current value of `data`.

The `MERGE JOIN` works as follows:

1. The copy of `t1 (id, name)` is created, sorted on `id`
2. The copy of `t2 (id, data)` is created, sorted on `id`
3. The pointers are set to the minimal values in both tables:

   ```
   >1  2<
    2  3
    2  4
    3  5
   ```
4. The pointers are compared in a loop, and if they match, the records are returned. If they don't match, the pointer with the minimal value is advanced:

   ```
   >1  2<  - no match, left pointer is less. Advance left pointer
    2  3
    2  4
    3  5

    1  2<  - match, return records and advance both pointers
   >2  3
    2  4
    3  5

    1  2  - match, return records and advance both pointers
    2  3< 
    2  4
   >3  5

    1  2 - the left pointer is out of range, the query is over.
    2  3
    2  4<
    3  5
   >
   ```

> In such a case, making the query more complex could make it faster because less rows are subjected to the join-level tests?

Sure.

Your query without the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  T1.name, T2.date
FROM    T1, T2
```

is more simple but returns more results and runs longer.

Comment: Don't joins generally do cross joins for the non-unique values?  That is to say that after the second step of step 4 of Merge Join, it should increment the left pointer but not the right one, and actually maintain 3 distinct pointers, and 4 in the more general case. (where table B has a second 2 as well)  In the horrific case that all the values are identical, there really should be n*m result rows.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table

Comment: Yeah, oops.  It should only be 3, because you only need one nested loop.

Comment: hash index maybe based on some memory engine, not for all engines? right?

Comment: @brucenan: what do you mean?

Comment: Your pseudo-graphics, sir, made this answer absolutely brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

Be careful of conflating too many different things.  You have a logical cost of the query based on number of rows to be examined, a (possibly) smaller logical cost based on number of rows actually returned and an unrelated a physical cost based on number of pages that have to be examined.

The three are related, but not strongly.

The number of rows examined is the largest of these costs and least easy to control.  The rows have to be matched through the join algorithm.  This, also, is the least relevant.

The number of rows returned is more costly because that's I/O bandwidth between client application and database.

The number of pages read is the most costly because that's an even larger number of physical I/O's.  That's the most costly because that's load inside the database with impact on all clients.

SQL Query with one table is **O**( *n* ).  That's the number of rows.  It's also **O**( *p* ) based on the number of pages.

With more than one table, the rows examined is **O**(n*m*...).  That's the nested-loops algorithm.    Depending on the cardinality of the relationship, however, the result set may be as small as **O**( *n* ) because the relationships are all 1:1.  But each table must be examined for matching rows.

A Hash Join replaces **O**( n*log(n) ) index + table reads with **O**( n ) direct hash lookups.  You still have to process **O**( *n* ) rows, but you bypass some index reads.

A Merge Join replaces **O**( n*m ) nested loops with **O**( log(n+m)*(n+m) ) sort operation.

With indexes, the *physical* cost may be reduced to **O**(log(n)*m) if a table is merely checked for existence.   If rows are required, then the index speeds access to the rows, but all matching rows must be processed.  **O**(n*m) because that's the size of the result set, irrespective of indexes.

The pages examined for this work *may* be smaller, depending on the selectivity of the index.

The point of an index isn't to reduce the number of rows examined so much.  It's to reduce the physical I/O cost of fetching the rows.

Comment: Without indexes, the nested loops algorithm will almost never be chosen by any decent engine. It will be either `HASH JOIN` or a `MERGE JOIN`.

Comment: It seems your answer and Quassnoi's complete each other.  One for the indexed version and the other for not.  I would say that in the indexed case for Merge Join, if it follows the strategy put forth by Quassnoi, it would be O(n+m).  However, if it was smart, it would compare O(n+m) and O(m log(n)), take the smaller, and then use the above strategy or use the index to find the results in table n, which btw should be the larger table.

Answer (score 1):

> Are SQL query execution times O(n) compared to the number of joins, if indexes are not used?

Generally they're going to be O(n^m), where n is the number of records per table involved and m is the number of tables being joined.

> And can indexing improve the actual big-O time-complexity, or does it only reduce the entire query time by some constant factor?

Both. Indexes allow for direct lookup when the joins are heavily filtered (i.e. with a good WHERE clause), and they allow for faster joins when they're on the right columns.

Indexes are no help when they're not on the columns being joined or filtered by.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how [clustered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx) vs [non-clustered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx) work

That is from a pure technical point of view...for an easy explanation my good buddy mladen has written a simple [article to understand](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/18/Back-To-Basics-What-is-a-Clustered-and-a-Non-Clustered.aspx) indexing.

Indexes definately help but I do recommend the reads to understand the pros and cons.