# Joining multiple records on the right side of a join to 1 record on the left side

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns analytics style information about a job board and where applicants are coming from in the following structure:

[image: Data format for query]

The query to access that is:

```
SELECT   g.name AS [Source]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Clicks]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Clicks]
        ,COUNT(v.id) AS [Total Clicks]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Applicants]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Applicants]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Applicants]
        ,SUM(v.cost/100.0) AS [Spend]
FROM a_views v
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_views a
    ON v.viewerid = a.viewerid
    AND v.sessionsourceid = a.sessionsourceid
    AND a.applicant = 1
JOIN a_sources s
    ON v.sourceid = s.id
JOIN a_sourcegroups g ON s.fk_sourcegroup = g.id
--JOIN jobs j ON v.jobid = j.anal_id AND j.featured = 1
WHERE v.hostName = @jobboard
    AND v.viewed_at >= @start AND v.viewed_at <= @end
GROUP BY g.name
```

The only issue is that in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN a_views` block there may be multiple records returned. What I need to do is only have the record tracked once in the `Click` sums but each time it's found for the `Applicant` sums.

I did find a similar question of this happening on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/916426/526895), but the answerer didn't actually give much information.

To resum what I need, each instance of the record in the right side of the join, but only 1 instance of the record on the left side.

Comment: Use the `Group By` function and aggregate functions on the repeated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this without changing your query entirely is separate the Click sums and Applicant sums into two separate queries, `UNION` them together and then group/sum them again.

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
SELECT
        Source
        ,SUM([Organic Clicks])
        ,.....
FROM
(
SELECT   g.name AS [Source]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Clicks]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Clicks]
        ,COUNT(v.id) AS [Total Clicks]
        ,0 AS [Organic Applicants]
        ,0 AS [Paid Applicants]
        ,0 AS [Total Applicants]
        ,SUM(v.cost/100.0) AS [Spend]
FROM
        ClickOnlyTables

UNION ALL

SELECT   g.name AS [Source]
        ,0 AS [Organic Clicks]
        ,0 AS [Paid Clicks]
        ,0 AS [Total Clicks]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Applicants]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Applicants]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Applicants]
        ,0 AS [Spend]
FROM
        ApplicantTables
)
GROUP BY
        Source
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I don't think you want a self join to answer this question.  Perhaps just aggregating a_views once solves the problem, first by applicant and then by game.

I find it hard to determine what you intend from your query, but something like this as the first aggregation:

```
select g.name, valuationDups.viweerid, v.sessionsourceid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Clicks],
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Clicks],
       COUNT(v.id) AS [Total Clicks],
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Organic Applicants],
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 AND v.cost <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Paid Applicants],
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.applicant = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Applicants],
       SUM(v.cost/100.0) AS [Spend]       
FROM a_views v JOIN
     a_sources s
     ON v.sourceid = s.id JOIN
     a_sourcegroups g
     ON s.fk_sourcegroup = g.id
WHERE v.hostName = @jobboard and
      v.viewed_at >= @start AND
      v.viewed_at <= @end
group by g.name, valuationDups.viweerid, v.sessionsourceid
```

And then aggregate again by g.name.

Comment: I should have said in my question that the reason I need the self join is because 1 record will contain cost and then another will have the applicant bit field.

Comment: @DaveLong . . . you can combine them together using an aggregation.  I don't know your logic, but `max(applicant)` and `sum(cost)` seem useful for this purpose.