# How can A left outer join B return more rows than are in A?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, outer-join

What is it wrong about this simple SQL outer join?

```
select count(*) from A -- 25766
select count(*) from B -- 1242
select count(*) from A left outer join B on A.b = B.b -- 310176
```

return 25766, 1242 and 310176 rows respectively. (This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2012.) How can `A left outer join B` ever return more rows than exist in `A`, especially given [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) Venn diagram? I guess I'm making a stupid mistake but what is it?

Comment: Can it be that the column b is not the whole key?

Comment: +1 I'll check. How could this explain 310176?

Comment: If b is only the part of the key it can be that one line in A reference a lot more lines in B and if in your example 1 record of A reference 12,0... rows in B you get your result.

Comment: @Jens I guess it's the same argument as in hvd's answer, right?

Comment: Yes it is the same argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can happen when column `b` is not unique in table `B`. Suppose you have this data:

```
  A      B
+---+  +---+---+
| b |  | b | c |
+---+  +---+---+
| 1 |  | 2 | 1 |
| 2 |  | 2 | 2 |
+---+  +---+---+
```

When you left-join from `A` to `B` on column `b`, you get

```
+-----+------+------+
| A.b | B.b  | B.c  |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 | NULL | NULL |
|   2 |    2 |    1 |
|   2 |    2 |    2 |
+-----+------+------+
```

which gives three rows in total, even though both `A` and `B` only have two rows each.

Comment: +1 Yes, `select count(distinct b) from B` returns 197, and 197 << 1242.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing strange about it (and this situation applies to inner joins too). A left outer join:

- Returns all rows from A cross B where the join condition match
- And returns all rows from A where the join condition does not match

So at minimum the query will return 25766 rows but there could be more. It is possible to have one row in table A that matches many rows in table B. Example:

```
A             B             Result
+----+----+  +-----+----+   +------+-----+-----+------+
|  id|   b|  |   id|   b|   |  a.id|  a.b|  b.b|  b.id|
+----+----+  +-----+----+   +------+-----+-----+------+
|   1|  10|  |  123|  10|   |     1|   10|   10|   123|
+----+----+  |  456|  10|   |     1|   10|   10|   456|
             +-----+----+   +------+-----+-----+------+
```

This returns two rows even though there is one row in table A.