# My sql query duplicates on crystal reports

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Im having trouble why my query(on sql server) is duplicating on crystal reports. Providing the screenshots of my work! This is  my code.

```
            myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Issuance.i_ID, ProductSold.ps_pID, ProductSold.ps_Name, ProductSold.ps_Qty,Issuance.i_Issued,Issuance.i_Received,Issuance.i_Received,Issuance.i_Approved,Issuance.i_Purposed,ProductSold.ps_Amount,ProductSold.ps_Serial,Issuance.i_EntryDate FROM Issuance LEFT JOIN ProductSold ON Issuance.i_ID = ProductSold.ps_IssID WHERE Issuance.i_ID='" + txtIssuanceID.Text + "'", myConnection);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            myConnection.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds, "Issuance");
            sda.Fill(ds, "ProductSold");
            rptMCT report = new rptMCT();
            report.SetDataSource(ds);
            report.VerifyDatabase();
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

[img-sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94h82.jpg),

[img-output in crystal reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3zoI.jpg), Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, just a side note, but you should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Seems you LEFT JOIN returns duplicated results due to returning all rows matched with the left table (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table). Try experimenting with your query to limit the results for just 2 records.

Comment: exactly what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your query. almost all of the time, Joins duplicate the results of the crystal reports, because it would just replicate the output of your SQL statement. You have to verify first in your query explorer of your DBMS if your query produces your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your image shows the join:

```
from ProductSold left join Issuance
```

But your code sample shows the opposite. The same problem exists in the where clause - where you compare your text value (sql injection vulnerability) to the preserved table in your join.