# Laravel DB query builder with LEFT JOIN using a RAW expression

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I would like to `left join` data from a `many-to-many` relationship. In my first attempt to solve the problem I ended up with the situation described at  [How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table)

Now I thought that I concatenate the values from the `many-to-many` relationship before I do the `left join`, but I'm stuck again and not getting anywhere. I managed to come up with partial solutions, but I don't know how to combine them into the final solution.

The query

```
SELECT 
    groups.id as `groups.id`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(choices.text) AS choices
FROM `input-choices` choices
    LEFT JOIN `input-choice_input-group` pivot ON choices.id = `pivot`.`input-choice_id`
    LEFT JOIN `input-groups` groups ON groups.id = `pivot`.`input-group_id`
WHERE groups.id = 2
GROUP BY groups.id
```

(`WHERE groups.id = 2` would finally change to `` WHERE groups.id = `input-types`.`input-group.id` ``
)

produces e. g. a result set like:

```
groups.id | choices 
2         | 1,2,3,4,5
```

As next step I thought it makes sense to left join the result from the previous query with the Query Builder `DB::raw()` method, but I got stuck again.

```
$survey = DB::table('questions')
->join('question_survey', function ($join) {
    $join->on('questions.id', '=', 'question_survey.question_id')
        ->where('question_survey.survey_id', '=', 1);
})
->leftJoin('answer_question_survey', 'question_survey.id', '=', 'answer_question_survey.question_survey_id')
->leftJoin('answers', 'answer_question_survey.answer_id', '=', 'answers.id')
->leftJoin('input-types', 'input-types.id', '=', 'questions.input-type_id')
->leftJoin(DB::raw(...), 'input-types.input-group.id', '=', '?.groups.id')
->select(
    'questions.id AS question.id',
    'questions.text AS question.text',
    'questions.explanation AS question.explanation',
    'questions.is_required AS question.is_required',
    'questions.input-type_id AS question.input-type_id',
    'input-types.id AS input-type.id',
    'input-types.name AS input-type.name',
    'input-types.input-group_id AS input-type.input-group_id',
    'question_survey.id AS question_survey.id',
    'question_survey.question_id AS question_survey.question_id',
    'question_survey.survey_id AS question_survey.survey_id',
    'question_survey.parent_id AS question_survey.parent_id',
    'answer_question_survey.id AS answer_question_survey.id',
    'answer_question_survey.question_survey_id AS answer_question_survey.question_survey_id',
    'answer_question_survey.answer_id AS answer_question_survey.answer_id',
    'answers.id AS answer.id',
    'answers.text AS answer.text'
)
->get();
```

1. How to use the first query inside the `DB::raw()` method. I'm always getting errors like "Syntax error or access violation: ..."
2. How would I complete the join condition `'input-types.input-group.id', '=', '?.groups.id'` because I don't know the name of the table I join.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to put your sub-query into select part as DB::raw().

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. I tried to implement your solution, but somehow it did not work. For a quick test I extended the query with `... 'answers.text AS answer.text', DB::raw('SELECT * FROM [BACKTICK]input-types[BACKTICK]'))->get();...`, but I just get error message _Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for   
  the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM `input-types` from `questions` inner join `question_survey` on `qu' at line 1_