# Left join in subquery

Tags: subquery, left-join, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to do a left join on my main table using this code

```
select distinct    VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                               VBen.BENF_COD_SEXE AS Sexe,
                               VBen.BENF_DAT_NAISS AS DatNaiss,
                               VBen.BENF_DAT_DECES AS DatDec,
                               A.date_ch as date_chsld

from PROD.V_FICH_ID_BEN_CM AS VBen 

left   join  (select distinct VAss.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                              vass.BENF_DD_ADMIS_ASSU_MED as date_ch
               from Prod.V_ADMIS_ASSU_MED_PLAN_PRIOR_CM as vass ) as A   

   on VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS =A. benbanls
   where Vben.BENF_DAT_NAISS>'2016-04-01' or Vben.BENF_DAT_DECES>'2011-04-01'
```

The problem is that the query result is a table with of number of rows greater than the main table with the same where 'condition'. I don't understand what I am missing

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it a problem?
The results simply indicate you have a 1:M (one to many) relationship between VBen:Vass(A)

If you don't have a 1:M relationship and it should be 1:1 then...

- you're missing join criteria between the tables.
- you should be getting a min/max on your date instead of all dates per benbanls

To better understand and answer we would need to know what VBen and Vass actually represent; but to put simply, you have multiple `VASS(A)` per `VBEN`

To illustrate with an example: Think about Order_Header and Order_Line tables...

Order_header contains (order_Number PK)
Order_line contains (Order_Number, Order_Line PK)

An order can have multiple lines, each line could have it's own ship date several items may have gone out on the same shipment/day. where some that were backordered went out on a different day.  In this situation, an order would still have multiple lines even though we distinct order_number and shipmentdate in a subquery.  I would guess your situation is similar.

so 1 in base table * 2 rows in derived/lines table gives us 2 records

1 < 2 which is the situation you have now; and that to me is perfectly fine and expected if it's a 1:M relationship.

- Maybe you need to do a min or max on date instead of a distinct?
- If not you're missing join criteria to make a 1:1 relationship
- maybe your expectation is just flawed.

The below will give you a 1:1 relationship but I'm not sure it's what you're after.

```
SELECT distinct VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                VBen.BENF_COD_SEXE AS Sexe,
                VBen.BENF_DAT_NAISS AS DatNaiss,
                VBen.BENF_DAT_DECES AS DatDec,
                A.date_ch as date_chsld
FROM PROD.V_FICH_ID_BEN_CM AS VBen 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT VAss.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                   Max(vass.BENF_DD_ADMIS_ASSU_MED) as date_ch
            FROM Prod.V_ADMIS_ASSU_MED_PLAN_PRIOR_CM as vass 
            GROUP BY VAss.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS) as A   
       on VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS = A. benbanls
 WHERE (Vben.BENF_DAT_NAISS>'2016-04-01' 
    or Vben.BENF_DAT_DECES>'2011-04-01)
```

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I was missing I should be using min on the date since an ID could have more than one date_ch

Comment: Don't thin you need the distinct anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there is more than one counterpart in the detail table of a record on the main table.

I try your scenario on my db get a correct result.

**In my DB:**

```
select distinct p.PollId as PollId,
                p.Title AS Title,                               
                p.InsertDate AS DatDec,
                ps.date_ch as date_chsld
  from dbo.Poll AS p 
  left join  (select distinct pSt.PollId as pollId,
                              Max(pSt.InsertDate) as date_ch
               from dbo.PollStore as pSt 
           Group by pSt.PollId ) as ps   
on p.PollId =ps.pollId
```

**As Your Query like this :**

```
select distinct    VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                               VBen.BENF_COD_SEXE AS Sexe,
                               VBen.BENF_DAT_NAISS AS DatNaiss,
                               VBen.BENF_DAT_DECES AS DatDec,
                               A.date_ch as date_chsld    
please try this query     
from PROD.V_FICH_ID_BEN_CM AS VBen     
left   join  (select distinct VAss.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as benbanls,
                              Max(vass.BENF_DD_ADMIS_ASSU_MED) as date_ch
               from Prod.V_ADMIS_ASSU_MED_PLAN_PRIOR_CM Group by VAss.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS as vass ) as A   
   on VBen.BENF_NO_INDIV_BEN_BANLS =A. benbanls
   where Vben.BENF_DAT_NAISS>'2016-04-01' or Vben.BENF_DAT_DECES>'2011-04-01'
```