# python - doing a left merge and getting wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, merge

df1:

```
id      score
1000    174
1001    181
1002    162
1003    182
1005    97
...     ...
3313    95
3316    91
3322    151

*1928 rows × 2 columns
```

df2:

```
date        id
01/03/2019  1002    
01/03/2019  1004    
01/03/2019  1013    
01/03/2019  1014
01/03/2019  1015
...         ... 
31/08/2019  3584
31/08/2019  3585
31/08/2019  3586
31/08/2019  3587
31/08/2019  3588
355775 rows × 3 columns
```

I want to get an output with the all the ids and scores from df1 and merge it with only the relevant dates from df2.

my code is `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='id')` and for some reason I'm getting back also the not relevant dates.

What is wrong here?

Comment: pd.merge(df2, df1, on="id")  you should use df2 as left if you want to put score next to dates.

Comment: It still doesn't work. it gives back wrong dates too

Comment: Just a guess: you have the same ID with multiple dates.

Comment: at df1 the IDs are unique. at df2 the same ID with multiple dates

Comment: If you have multiple test dates for ID in df2, pandas has no way of knowing the “correct” date for a particular ID and hence all dates for that ID will be returned matched to the same score.

Comment: Thanks. How I get around it? Is there an equivalent in Python3 for LEFT JOIN in SQL?

Comment: This is not a matter of left join. You do not have enough information in your data to identify the date of the score uniquely. SQL would give you the same output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is the answer. If ID is unique in df1, but not in df2, pandas has no way of knowing the “correct” date from df2 and hence all dates will be merged to the same score for a given ID.

I suspect you would need a third dataframe where you have information that matches the (presumably) best score to the number of attempts, or something similar.

This is not a coding problem, but rather data availability. As a matter of fact your original code is fine, but only with the right inputs.