# Issue when joining 3 temp tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an issue joining 3 temp tables.

I am going to write the whole code but the thing that doesn't work is a join when selecting all three temp tables. Everything else works just fine (type just in case if someone wants to see the whole picture).

I need to join all three tables on dates to make sure I select the same inventory during the same time period. Whenever I join those three tables I either get Forecast or Actuals right, but never both.

Answer (score 0):

> When I type this I get Forecast correct, but Actuals incorrect a.[DMDPostDate]=u.[STARTDATE] and f.[STARTDATE]=a.[DMDPostDate] (Forecast correct 6998.649, Actuals are not correct 826)

> -- AND u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] and f.[STARTDATE]=u.[STARTDATE] (Actuals are correct 10369, Forecast not correct 8322.315)

> -- and a.[DMDPostDate]=f.[STARTDATE] (Forecast correct 6998.649, Actuals not correct)

> -- AND u.[STARTDATE]=a.[DMDPostDate] (Forecast correct 6998.649, Actuals not correct)

> -- AND u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] (Actuals are correct 10369, Forecast not correct)

> -- and u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] and u.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] (Forecast correct 6998.649, Actuals not correct)

From your post - it seems fairly clear that joining STARTDATEs gets you the correct actuals, and joining DMDPostDate to either start date gets the right forecast.

Something thing to consider - u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] - this clause should have no impact to the A table join, what if you added this to the F table ON clause, and then u.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] to the A table clause

The way it's working now, you're left joining everything from table F to everything it can join to in table A based on the U.[UPC]=F.[DMDUNIT] AND U.[MASTERCHAINNAME]=F.[LOC], without any dates. It could be a challenge with the way it's evaluating the clauses as a result.

**Dark horse answer** - you don't need to join on any dates - actuals are correct when you aren't joining dates for the A table - when you use AND u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] it may be applying to the U/F join which could lower the forecast number.

You could also troubleshoot by joining the F and A tables separately to the U table to see if you're getting the expected values then.

Best guess -

```
SELECT 
    U.[UPC] AS 'Item', 
    U.[MASTERCHAINNAME] AS 'Chain', 
    U.[STARTDATE] AS 'Start Date', 
    U.[EVENT_TYPE] , 
    U.[EVENT_NAME], 
    SUM(F.Forecast) AS 'Forecast', 
    SUM(A.HistoryQuantity) AS 'Actuals'
FROM
    UDT_CKB_SNAPSHOT U  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    FCSTPERFSTATIC F ON U.[UPC] = F.[DMDUNIT] 
                     AND U.[MASTERCHAINNAME] = F.[LOC] 
                     AND f.[STARTDATE] = u.[STARTDATE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    HISTWIDE_CHAIN A ON U.[UPC] = a.[DMDUNIT] 
                     AND U.[MASTERCHAINNAME] = a.[LOC] 
                     AND a.[DMDPostDate] = u.[STARTDATE] 
GROUP BY 
    U.[UPC], U.[MASTERCHAINNAME], U.[STARTDATE], U.[EVENT_TYPE] , U.[EVENT_NAME]
```

Comment: regarding the first point, do you mean and f.[STARTDATE]=a.[DMDPostDate] and u.[STARTDATE]=a.[DMDPostDate] ? If so, it didn't give a proper calculation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the second idea...

Comment: And in terms of the 'dark horse answer' when I don't join on any dates it is completely incorrect data.

Comment: Was a weird thought problem - the best steps may be to separate the problem by joining the U/F table and U/A tables separately. I'm guessing that the U/F join will need u.[STARTDATE]=f.[STARTDATE] added into the join criteria, and the U/A join will use this version you posted u.[STARTDATE] = a.[DMDPostDate] - this is what I was suggesting with the second idea. I added in what I mean as an edit under "Best guess".

Comment: After looking back, I deleted the original first point - it was definitely out of scope after I spent some more time with your problem.

Comment: If you can get the singular joins between U/F working and U/A working, it may be worth dumping those in two more CTE's and joining them after they group. The left joins will tack on extra rows into the left table if they can, which is likely part of the issue in the final summing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table

Comment: Procopypaster thank you for the idea. Unfortunately it completely gave me a different result. For 9781419741906 where I need to see Forecast =6998.649  I get 2353.184 and for Actuals I need to see 10369 and I get 6608. I am not sure why it is like that, separately they do work...

Comment: Interesting, they work separately as in the U/F join works and the U/A join works? Could you do the group by on those two separate sets and then join them together after? Or is that what still didn't work?