# Oracle Left join returns more records than in left table

Tags: oracle, left-join

I am joining couple of Oracle tables on 2 separate fields. If first join fails, then I join on a second field. I am using left joins
However when doing the second join, I am getting a lot more records, most likely because there are multiple values found in table 2

Any suggestions how I can remove duplicates on the 2 joins I am doing.

Thanks

```
select v.* from
(select 
t.*
from 
(select x.* from table1 x
MINUS
select x.* from table1 x
join table2 u
on x.postcode = u.postcodelocator) t) v

left join from table2 w
on v.AL1_POST_TOWN_NAME = w.TOWNNAME
```

Comment: How you define a duplicate and what you would want to do with those duplicates is entirely dependent on you and your data. So imagine you sat down with pen and paper to "join" these tables and write out each resultant record. What logic would you, in your brain, apply to determine what you write down on that paper, record by record. If you can explain that to us, we can help you write that same logic in SQL. It may help if you share sample data from these tables and desired results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. (Required if debugging.) Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: What do you mean, "duplicates"? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/3404097) [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097) PS  [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   (...) v
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 w ON ...
```

You never return any values from `table2` as you `SELECT v.*` so it does not matter if the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` matches or not as the `JOIN` will not remove any rows from the driving table and will duplicate rows in the driving table if there are duplicates in the joined column in the outer joined table.

So, if you want to remove the duplicates from the `JOIN` then just remove the `OUTER JOIN` and use:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   (...) v
```

Which then looks like you could simplify the entire query down to:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table2 t2
                   WHERE  t1.postcode = t2.postcodelocator)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This query does work partly.                                                
For those records which have  no matching postcode in table2, I would then need to try match on AL1_POST_TOWN_NAME and return only the matching records

Comment: @user3050151 You have never before mentioned `AL1_POST_TOWN_NAME`. How are we supposed to know how to match on it?

Comment: I did. Please see initial post