# Left join results in more rows than there are in the left table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the number of unique rows that are in the left table with a left join but I get more rows (121471) then there are in the left table (121275).

My CTE looks like this.

```
WITH merch_seasons AS
(
    SELECT DISTCINT fan_id,
        (SELECT transaction_season
         FROM merch_with_current_season
         WHERE merchandise_fan_id_purchaser = fan_id
           AND transaction_season IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY transaction_season
         LIMIT 1) AS 'merch_first_season',
        (SELECT transaction_season
         FROM merch_with_current_season
         WHERE merchandise_fan_id_purchaser = fan_id
           AND transaction_season IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY transaction_season DESC
         LIMIT 1) AS 'merch_last_season'
    FROM
        fans 
    LEFT JOIN
        merch_with_current_season ON fan_id = merchandise_fan_id_purchaser
),
```

I use this same cte for other subsets as well and they return the same amount of rows there are in the left table, not sure why this one does not return the same amount. I look forward to everyone's answers.

Thanks!

#### EDIT

To make it reproducable

```
CREATE TABLE fans (
    fan_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE merch_with_current_season (
    merchandise_fan_id_purchaser INT,
    transaction_season VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO fans (fan_id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);

INSERT INTO merch_with_current_season (merchandise_fan_id_purchaser, transaction_season) VALUES
(1, '22-23'),
(1, '21-22'),
(2, '21-22'),
(3, '12-13'),
(3, NULL);
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I expect it's MySQL/MariaDB, because other DBMSs would rightly complain that this is not valid SQL, but this is a different issue. Still, with MariaDB this returns the same amount of tuples as in `fans` (3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916414/how-can-a-left-outer-join-return-more-records-than-exist-in-the-left-table)

Comment: It's common for a JOIN to add rows to a result set. If the JOIN condition matches multiple rows on the right table for any rows on the LEFT table, that is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with a left join but I get more rows (121471) then there are in the left table (121275).

We have this excerpt describing the JOIN:

```
FROM
    fans 
LEFT JOIN
    merch_with_current_season ON fan_id = merchandise_fan_id_purchaser
```

Based on that, look for duplicate `merchandise_fan_id_purchaser` values in the `merch_with_current_season` table.

LEFT JOIN does **not** automatically guarantee exactly one match for each row from the left table; it only guarantees *at least* one row in the results for each row from the left table. Extra rows are **expected** if there are multiple rows in the right table that match the conditional expression in the `ON` clause. In this case, that would be multiple `merch_with_current_season` rows that can match the `ON` condition for a given `fans` row.

If you want **exactly one result row** per left-table row, you have a few options:

1. Refine the conditional expressions in the `ON` clause to be more precise
2. JOIN to a subquery on the right table that groups by the key field from the left side of the table
3. Use a LATERAL join (APPLY in SQL Server).
4. Use a row_number() windowing function with appropriate PARTITION BY expression, and filter to rows where the result is 1
5. GROUP BY the fields you need from the left table, and then use aggregation on the fields from the other table.

I could probably come up with more. The point is the exact or most appropriate solution depends on other areas we don't know about yet.